# getting errors instead getting stored WIFI Passwords

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I created a Python script which displays all passwords that are stored on the computer by calling external commands by using the `subprocess` module.

I just want to get all passwords that are stored on my computer, but when I executed the script I get an error instead of getting the result:

> TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])
data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
profiles = [x.split(':')[1][1:-1] for x in data if 'All User Profile' in x]
for i in profiles:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear'])
    results.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    results = [y.split(':')[1][1:-1] for y in results if 'Key Content' in y]
    try:
        print('{:<30}| {:<}'.format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print('{:<30}| {:<}'.format(i, ''))
```

Comment: Decode and split don’t operate in place, you need to reassign that back to result and data respectively.

Comment: you mean I should place `decode` and `split` respectively to the result declaration @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't to break this statement like the following:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])
data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

the above statement is what brought an error in my script but the solution is to do it like

```
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

and this now work properly

Answer (score 1):

`data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')` is producing a nice list, but it doesn't put that list into the variable `data`, you need to reassign the process to `data` and do the same for `results`

```
data = data.decode('utf-8').split('\n')

   results = results.decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

There may be other issues but this will account for why what you thought was a list of strings is actually still the bytes object so you are iterating over the byte (int) not a string.

Comment: hi there dear Tadhg - first of all many thanks: for me it does not work - I am on Python 3.8.2 on anaconda: i get back    data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,

  File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh' -what to do now!?